# How to analyze two different signal duration -ECG

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have two sets of ecg signals from different source and with different duration. One set has time duration of 3min and the other set has time duration of 5 secs.
The problem I have is that I do not know what technique to use to combine these signals. My goal is to be able to locate the QRS end-point and then extract important segments for common analysis

Answer (score 0):

What kind of combine (does it means overlap or join ?). You should not join two signal arrays as discontinuities at array junction will hamper your results. You can always resample (or normalize) signals from different sources into your sampling frequency and analyse signals as 5sec frames